# How to Improve and speed up this PHP script that uses a nested loop?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop, inner-join

I wrote a PHP script that joins two tables to display information in this format:

```
Jane Doe
Phone: 082 980 9514
Home Loan Applications (Active) - 17/07/2013
Credit Report (Free Report) (Unsubscribed) 12/06/2013
```

You'll notice that the first and lastname is in the first line of the output, followed by the phone number and then the mailing lists they've been subscribed. Next to the list is the status. Active means that the user has not unsubscribed and is still active while the unsubscribed date is displayed if the user already opted out of the mailing list. Then it is followed by the registration date of the subscriber to a certain mailing list.

Here's the link to the sample tables: **[Tables](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aj6h3OU7BYcmdEJzWFNpRHdiWklYUDRfOGtlb2lxV1E&usp=sharing)**

It works as it should but it takes forever to complete since there are about 76,000 records in 1 table and about 100,000 in the other. I would like to ask suggestions on how to optimize the code to speed up the script.

Here's the current code that I've written:

```
$resultarray = array();

$rs4 = mysqli_query($con1,"SELECT interspire_customfield.subscriberid, interspire_customfield.fname, interspire_customfield.lname, interspire_customfield.phone, emailaddress, subscribedate, unsubscribed, interspire_customfield.listid, listname FROM `interspire_subscriber` INNER JOIN `interspire_customfield` ON interspire_subscriber.subscriberid = interspire_customfield.subscriberid GROUP BY emailaddress");

while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs4)) {
        $resultarray[] = $row4['subscriberid'].",".$row4['fname'].",".$row4['lname'].",".$row4['phone'].",".$row4['emailaddress'];
}

foreach ($resultarray as $arrlist) {

    $arr = explode(',', $arrlist);
    $sid = $arr[0];
    $frstname = $arr[1];
    $lstname = $arr[2];
    $pnum = $arr[3];
    $emailadd = $arr[4];

    echo $frstname." ".$lstname."<br />";
    echo "Phone: ".$pnum."<br />";

    $rs5 = mysqli_query($con1,"SELECT interspire_customfield.subscriberid, subscribedate, unsubscribed, interspire_customfield.listid, listname FROM interspire_subscriber INNER JOIN interspire_customfield ON interspire_subscriber.subscriberid = interspire_customfield.subscriberid WHERE interspire_subscriber.emailaddress = '$emailadd' GROUP BY interspire_subscriber.listid");

    if (!$rs5) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}

    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs5)) {
        $listname = $row5['listname'];
        $subdate = $row5['subscribedate'];
        $unsub = $row5['unsubscribed'];

        if($unsub == "0"){
            $stat = "Active";
        }else{
            $stat = date('d/m/Y', $unsub);
        }

        $subdt = date('d/m/Y', $subdate);

        echo "* $listname ($stat) - $subdt <br />";
    }
        echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: seems like it's your mysql beein slow. Check the slow query log

Comment: Have you used any indexes in MySQL?

Comment: Perform a singular select query with multiple `WHERE` clauses, instead of doing them implicitly in a loop.

Comment: Why are you calling and overriding your `SELECT` query in each step of your `foreach`?

Comment: @Soundz: Thanks, I'll go check it out.

Comment: @pascalvgemert: Yes, in both tables, I used subscriberid as index.

Comment: @RainFromHeaven: I don't know how to write the singular query that would best fit my script. I don't quite get what you mean on your 2nd comment but I'm doing a while in the foreach to get the mailing lists that an emailaddress is subscribed to.

Comment: @maikelsabido another approach would be to store all output data in one variable and do only one `echo` at the end. But that speed increase might be marginal and you could experience a blank page untill the script is done

Comment: @Soundz Oh. Okay. So I think the script get so slow because it prints out every now and then... But could it be fast enough? The current code seems to be taking several hours. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there are indexes (if not, create it on subscriberid in both fields) in both tables try to use query without JOIN:

```
SELECT 
ic.subscriberid, 
ic.fname, 
ic.lname, 
ic.phone, 
ic.listid, 
emailaddress, 
subscribedate, 
unsubscribed, 
listname 
FROM `interspire_subscriber` isub, `interspire_customfield` ic
WHERE isub.subscriberid = ic.subscriberid
GROUP BY emailaddress
```

And use buffer to store strings before printing. You can use string value or array with join() method or just ob_start.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I determine the list down the lists that the subscriber is subscribed to like the example I've given above?

Comment: Just process data to arrays before listing it. Create tree-like structure: User - Subscribes
 - ...
 - Subscribes
   - subscribe1
   - ...
   - subscribe n
`

Answer (score 1):

Your intended output necessitates the determination of exactly one set of name and phone number per email address: yet because `interspire_subscriber` associates multiple `subscriberid` values with a single `emailaddress`, the join with `interspire_customfield` (which contains the name and phone number data) is not 1:1; thus it is possible that an email address may be associated with multiple different names and phone numbers.

Either you must group your output by `subscriberid` (which presumably will not satisfy your desired result of collating each user's list subscriptions), or you must change the schema: any such change must necessarily involve a one-time determination of which values from `interspire_customfield` should be associated with each `emailaddress`.  I would then suggest keying `interspire_customfield` on `emailaddress` (and dropping `listid` from that table and `subscriberid` from one of the tables, depending on whether it should be associated with a *subscriber* or a *subscription*).

With those changes made, you could do:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$qry = $dbh->query('
  SELECT   emailaddress,
           c.fname, c.lname, c.phone,
           s.subscribedate, s.unsubscribed, s.listname
  FROM     interspire_subscriber  AS s
      JOIN interspire_customfield AS c USING (emailaddress)
  ORDER BY emailaddress, s.listid
');

if ($qry) {
  echo '<ol>';

  $row = $qry->fetch();
  while ($row) {
    $current_email = $row['emailaddress'];
    echo '<li>',
           htmlentities($row['fname']),' ',htmlentities($row['lname']),'<br/>',
           'Phone: ',htmlentities($row['phone']),
           '<ul>';
    do {
      $unsub = $row['unsubscribed'];
      echo '<li>',htmlentities($row['listname']),
           ' (',$unsub ? 'Active' : date('d/m/Y', $unsub),')',
           ' - ',date('d/m/Y', $row['subscribedate']),
           '</li>';
    } while ($row = $qry->fetch() and $row['emailaddress'] == $current_email);
    echo   '</ul>',
         '</li>';
  }

  echo '</ol>';
}
```

As for speed, you should ensure you have defined a composite index on the `interspire_subscriber` table over `(emailaddress, listid)`; and a `UNIQUE` index on the `interspire_customfield` table over `(emailaddress)`.

Whilst we're at it, you may wish to consider whether `interspire_subscriber.listname` is required (it appears to be denormalised, as it ought to be associated with `listid` in some other table)?  You may also wish to consider storing temporal values using MySQL's native temporal data types instead of integers.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer/suggestion. I'll try this out. Thank you so much.